# Windows Server 2008 R2 DFS Replication - Which files are replicating?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

Windows Server 2008 R2 DFS Replication

Is it possible to see which specific files are replicating in real time using a GUI or command line tool or in a log somewhere?

I didn't see this in the DFS health reporting, in the DFS event viewer, or the DFS log. The log is pretty cryptic though so it may be in there and I'm unable to see it. I searched through the DFS log for paths and files I know should be replicating and they're not in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To monitor DFS, we wrote a small utility that interrogates the backlog via WMI of every server participating in a replication group to see what files are backlogged. When replication happens, those files get backlogged first, then after they transfer, they are removed from the backlog. This is as "real time" as we have been able to get as far as monitoring DFS.

You can also use `dfsrdiag.exe` to monitor the backlog. Here's an MS page on DFS monitoring: [DFS Replication: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773238%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_045)